# Creating UDF using VBA in excel to find similar values in a row where order does not matter

Tags: vba, excel, excel-udf

I am dealing with unlimited new rows of data every day and I need a **UDF** that would find similar row values regardless of its order. As you can see in the example bellow **A9:F9** and **A4:F4** has a similar row values marked as **SIMILAR ROW 1**. You need to look at the overall data within the row to see that it has same values but not in the same order. I’m not familiar with VBA if someone could please help me it would very well be appreciated. I have been searching for this all over the web now.

Formula Example:

```
=Similarity(Range Of Data from A:F, Row Of Data)
```

My sheet looks like below image:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) with **their** code. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pls. try with below code

```
Sub test()
    Dim data() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dd As Long
    Dim lastrow As Variant
    Dim lastcolumn As Variant
    Dim status As Boolean
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastcolumn = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ReDim data(lastrow - 1, lastcolumn)
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        For j = 1 To lastcolumn
            data(i - 1, j) = Cells(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    For i = 1 To lastrow - 1
        Call similarity(data(), i)
    Next i
End Sub


Public Function similarity(rdata() As String, currrow As Long)
    lastrow = UBound(rdata)
    matchcount = 0
    lastcolumn = UBound(rdata, 2)
    For Z = currrow To lastrow - 1
        ReDim test(lastcolumn) As String
        ReDim test1(lastcolumn) As String
        For i = 1 To lastcolumn
            test(i) = rdata(currrow, i)
            test1(i) = rdata(Z + 1, i)
        Next i
        Call sort(test())
        Call sort(test1())
        For i = 1 To lastcolumn
            If test(i) = test1(i) Then
                matchcount = matchcount + 1
            End If
        Next i
        If matchcount = lastcolumn Then
            If Cells(currrow + 1, lastcolumn + 1).Value <> "" Then
                Cells(currrow + 1, lastcolumn + 1).Value = Cells(currrow + 1, lastcolumn + 1).Value & "|" & "Match with " & Z + 2
            Else
                Cells(currrow + 1, lastcolumn + 1).Value = "Match with " & Z + 2
            End If
            If Cells(Z + 2, lastcolumn + 1).Value <> "" Then
                Cells(Z + 2, lastcolumn + 1).Value = Cells(Z + 2, lastcolumn + 1).Value & "|" & "Match with " & currrow + 1
            Else
                Cells(Z + 2, lastcolumn + 1).Value = "Match with " & currrow + 1
            End If
        End If
        matchcount = 0
    Next Z
End Function

Sub sort(list() As String)
    Dim First As Integer, Last As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim temp As String

    First = LBound(list)
    Last = UBound(list)
    For i = First To Last - 1
        For j = i + 1 To Last
            If list(i) > list(j) Then
                temp = list(j)
                list(j) = list(i)
                list(i) = temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: your code is very promising i like it but i don't seem to make it work sir.

Comment: why? whats the problem?

Comment: i pasted the entire code in the module then applied the udf. i am using excel 2007 maybe you must have miss something..

Comment: given code is not UDF. so run the subroutine test alone will give you the result

Comment: yes i also did that sir but line: "data(i - 1, j) = Cells(i, j)" seems to be an error. mismatch error 13

Comment: you data should be presented in A2 ie. starting at A2 to F14 . see the snap. Hope it will work.

Comment: =similarity(A2:F14,A2:F2 )? does this look legit? still couldn't figure it out sorry i even had help with my friends here.

Comment: don't use UDF similarity directly on cell. instead of that you need to run the sub test().

Comment: it wasn't what i was expecting but it works thanks dude!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start.  It will help you to find which rows are [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of other rows.  Say we start with:

[image]

This *UDF()* will take the contents of a set of cells; sort the data; concatenate the data; and return the result as a single string:

```
Public Function SortRow(rng As Range) As String
    ReDim ary(1 To rng.Count) As Variant
    Dim CH As String, i As Long
    CH = Chr(2)
    For i = 1 To 6
        ary(i) = rng(i)
    Next i
    Call aSort(ary)
    SortRow = Join(ary, CH)
End Function

Public Sub aSort(ByRef InOut)

    Dim i As Long, J As Long, Low As Long
    Dim Hi As Long, Temp As Variant

    Low = LBound(InOut)
    Hi = UBound(InOut)

    J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While J > 0
        For i = Low To Hi - J
          If InOut(i) > InOut(i + J) Then
            Temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next i
        For i = Hi - J To Low Step -1
          If InOut(i) > InOut(i + J) Then
            Temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next i
        J = J \ 2
    Loop
End Sub
```

So in **G1** we enter:

```
=SortRow(A1:F1)
```

and copy down and in **H1** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($G$1:$G$7,G1)=1,"unique combination","duplicates")
```

and copy down:

[image]

This shows that rows 2 and 6 have data that are duplicated, but in different order.

Starting from this may help you achieve your goal.